# query mysql to laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I write this query in MySQL

```
SELECT driver.nama_driver,pengiriman.status_pengiriman FROM driver
 LEFT JOIN pengiriman ON pengiriman.user_driver = driver.user_driver WHERE 

driver.user_driver="12aad" and pengiriman.status_pengiriman is null OR 

driver.user_driver="12add" and pengiriman.status_pengiriman = "Terkirim"`
```

and it shows nothing because I m selecting driver.user_driver who not in pengiriman table
but in Laravel it show something can someone help me
I want the output shows nothing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing parentheses:

```sql
SELECT driver.nama_driver,pengiriman.status_pengiriman
FROM driver
LEFT JOIN pengiriman ON pengiriman.user_driver = driver.user_driver WHERE 
   ( driver.user_driver="12aad" AND pengiriman.status_pengiriman IS NULL )
   OR ( driver.user_driver="12add" AND pengiriman.status_pengiriman = "Terkirim"`)
```